# Comparar elementos entre vectores y asignar una acción

Tags: python, lista, loops, if

Necesito un programa que compare los elementos de 3 vectores, solo si cada uno de los  elementos del vector A son menores que su CORRESPONDIENTE elemento del vector C y mayores a su CORRESPONDIENTE elemento del vector B, se imprime "si", caso contrario se imprime "no"

Estoy intentando con un for para que analice a todos los elementos 1x1 en este caso con estos vectores se debería imprimir "si", pero se imprime 3 veces "si", porque lo imprime cada vez que analiza una fila

Pero quiero que solo se imprima 1 vez si cumple la condición para todas las filas

```
A=[2,2,2]

B=[1,1,1]

C=[5,5,5]

for l in range(0,3):   
    if (A[l] >= B[l] and C[l] <= A[l]):
        print ("si")    
    else:
        print ("no")
```

ademas quisiera que sirva para vectores de cualquier dimensión no solo para vectores de 3  elementos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es ver si la condición **no** se cumple. Si en algún momento no se cumple, imprimes "no" y usas `break` para romper el ciclo. Si el ciclo se completa imprimes "si", esto lo puedes hacer con un `else`:

```
A=[2,2,2]

B=[1,1,1]

C=[5,5,5]

for l in range(len(A)):   
    if not (A[l] >= B[l] and  A[l] <= C[l]): # equivale a "if (A[l] < B[l] or A[l] > C[l]):"
        print ("no")
        break
else:
    print ("si")
```

Es más eficiente ver si alguno no cumple y entonces romper el ciclo que siempre comprobar todos los elementos.

**El `else` va al mismo nivel que el `for`**, no es un error de identación. En este caso el bloque del `else` se ejecuta si el `for` se completó (no se usó el `break`).

La condición es si son **iguales** o mayores/menores. Si deben ser estrictamente mayores o menores quita el igual.

Otra opción es usar `any`:

```
print('no' if any ((A[i] < B[i] or A[i] > C[i] for i in range(len(A)))) else "si")
```

**Edición:** para que te sirva para cualquier número de elementos solo tienes que usar `len`, lógicamente las tres listas han de ser iguales en logitud.

Comment: gracias me ayudo  mucho

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma muy elegante de resolver esto en python con muy pocas líneas de código, lo agrego como respuesta simplemente por que adoro estas cosas de Python, aunque excede un poco tu pregunta:

```
print("Si" if all([A[i] >= B[i] <= C[i] for i in range(len(A))]) else "Si")
```

Que es lo que hace esto?

1. Mediante la "comprensión" de listas, verificamos cada uno de los elementos de cada una de la lista de 0 a Len(A) mediante la función `range`. Asumimos que las tres listas tienen la misma cantidad de elementos.
2. Verificamos los tres elementos según tu ejemplo por índice `A[i] >= B[i] <= C[i]`, esto nos va a devolver True/False para cada elemento
3. Por último, usando la función `all` verificamos todos los valores, si todos son True, entonces el retorno va a ser True.
4. Por último imprimimos mediante una operación ternaria: {Valor si Verdadero} [condición] else {Valor si falso}

Comment: gracias me sirvió de mucho